# Using Octokit to fetch pull request within a date range

Tags: github, octokit, octokit-js

I'm using Octokit/rest js to fetch pull requests from a repository.

Ideally, I'd like to have pull requests from x date to y date depending on the creation date.

Is there a way to do this?

Right now I'm fetching all the pull requests and then iterating over them.

Ideally, I would like to passe some parameters on the request. This is what I'm doing now:

```
 const pullRequests = await octokit.paginate(
          '/repos/{owner}/{repo}/pulls',
          {
            owner: organization.providerLogin,
            repo: repository.name,
            state: 'all',
          },
```

This is what I would like to do:

```
 const pullRequests = await octokit.paginate(
          '/repos/{owner}/{repo}/pulls?q=createdat2022-04-01..2022-04-07',
          {
            owner: organization.providerLogin,
            repo: repository.name,
            state: 'all',
          },
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use `@octokit/rest` for this job with [GitHub's Search API](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/searching-on-github/searching-issues-and-pull-requests).

```js
const { Octokit } = require("@octokit/rest");

const octokit = new Octokit();

const prs = await octokit.rest.search.issuesAndPullRequests({
  q: `type:pr+repo:${organization.providerLogin}/${repository.name}+created:>=2022-01-01`,
  per_page: 100, // use the number you like
});

console.log(prs.data.items)
```

I created a RunKit where you can play with: https://runkit.com/dominguezcelada/625035fc20b0c4000842fde9

---

You can wrap the previous code snippet with `octokit.paginate()` to get all the paginated results.

> [Octokit Docs](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.js#pagination) recommend to use `octokit.paginate.iterator` so you can run the [iterator asynchronously](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of)

---

Let me know if this works or not. I would be happy to help you on that if necessary.

Comment: That helps a lot thank you.
This raises another concern: For this type of search, Octokit does not populate relations such as requested_reviewers. I can't find anything related to pull request relations in the GitHub search API documentation. Do you know if that's possible?

Comment: For that, I think you will need the power of GraphQL. If you want, you can open a new issue or update the current one, and then I can give you a working example you can get inspired from.